# Odd minute Probabililty

Tags: probability, statistics

During a soccer match of 90 minutes there are 30 fouls on average. How can I calculate the probability of at least one foul at minute x and the probability of at least a foul to happen on an odd minute?

Comment: You can start assuming that there is one third probability of a foul per minute.

Comment: To be clear:  you can't really "calculate" anything of the sort.  You can make some assumptions and you can derive results from those assumptions.  You can, for example, assume that the fouls follow a Poisson process (equally likely for a foul to occur in any given minute) but there's nothing in the problem that suggests that this is true (and I suspect it isn't true in real life).

Comment: lulu, I think I can safely enough assume they follow a Poisson Process, the thing I am not able to figure out is given roughly 1/3 probability of a foul per minute and 1/2 probability that a foul happens on an odd minute, how to get the probability for 30 fouls to happen only on even minutes or at least once on an even one (which should be the same)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an average of 30 fouls in 90 minutes, then the rate of fouls per
minute is $\lambda = 1/3,$ as @N74 says. Then the probability of at least
one foul in a *particular* minute is 
$$P(X \ge 1) = 1 - P(X=0) = 1- e^{-1/3} = 0.2835,$$
where $X \sim \mathsf{Pois}(\lambda = 1/3).$
In R statistical software:

```
1 - dpois(0, 1/3)
## 0.2834687
```

I have no idea what you mean by at least one foul in an 'odd minute'. Is that a
separate problem? Or somehow tangled up with the first part about minute `x`?
If you mean any odd numbered minute during 90 minutes, unrelated to the above, the rate for that
would be $\lambda = 15.$ I'll let you do the rest, depending on what
you mean.

Comment: Bruce thank you that is what I needed, I can figure out what I need from your answer, sorry for not making my question clear enough